# When using HashRouter in ReactJS this.props.location.state is undefined on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

[image]I have beer list page then on click of any item 
Opens up the details page.

The data in details page is passed through

```
<Link to=“{pathname:’beerDetails’,state:{selectedbeer:selectedbeer}}/>
```

On details page

***this.props.location.state is undefined when details page is refreshed***

When using HashRouter in ReactJS this.props.location.state is undefined on page refresh but page refresh retains the data when browserRouter is used

Comment: Can anybody please help me with this issue

Answer (score 3):

You have an open double-quote in your code example for the `Link` component.

As for using `HashRouter` and `location.state`, the documentation states the following:

> Hash history does not support location.key or location.state. In
>   previous versions we attempted to shim the behavior but there were
>   edge-cases we couldn’t solve. Any code or plugin that needs this
>   behavior won’t work. As this technique is only intended to support
>   legacy browsers, we encourage you to configure your server to work
>   with  instead.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter

As you have mentioned, it works with `BrowserRouter`. Unless you have a specific need to support older browsers, then you should use `BrowserRouter` which uses the HTML5 history API.

Comment: Thanks we switched to BrowserRouter as is does not support HTML5 history api

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me for `HashRouter`

- Pass data with `Link`

```
<Link to={{ 
 pathname: "/YOUR_PATH_HERE", 
 state: YOUR_DATA_TO_BE_PASSED 
}}>
 Navigate
</Link>
```

- Pass data with `push` function

```js
props.history.push({ 
 pathname: '/YOUR_PATH_HERE',
 state: YOUR_DATA_TO_BE_PASSED
});
```

Then in the destination component, I get my state as below:

```js
const {
    location: {
      state: YOUR_DATA_TO_BE_PASSED,
    },
} = props;

// my data
YOUR_DATA_TO_BE_PASSED
```

Comment: While this works for passing state from one location to another with HashRouter, the state is lost when you refresh the page (while it is preserved when using BrowserRouter)